# What's the meaning of If $ ϕ1,ϕ2 ∈ Hom(K^n, K^m) then Mϕ1+ϕ2 = Mϕ1 +Mϕ2 $

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, group-homomorphism

I've been asked the following questions:

1. $ϕ_1,ϕ_2 ∈ Hom(K^n, K^m)$ then $ Mϕ_1+ϕ_2 = Mϕ_1 +Mϕ_2 $
2. If $M_1,M_2 ∈ M_(n*m)(K) $ then  $ ϕ_(M_1+M_2) = ϕ_(M_1)+ ϕ_(M_2) $

But I don't know what is this meaning.  Does Hom means homomorphism? 
Which subject is this?

Can anyone explain it for me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hom.html

Comment: I can find no sense in this. Please, try and be more precise; what is $M$ in 1? What is $\phi$ in 2?